# Mongoose sub-schema not generating _id

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have two `Schema` objects:

contact.js:

```
/**
 * Contact Schema
 */
var ContactSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    role: String,
    phone: String,
    email: String,
    primary: Boolean
}, {timestamps: {createdAt: 'created', updatedAt: 'updated'}, _id: true, id: true});
```

client.js:

```
/**
 * Client Schema
 */
var ClientSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true
    },
    comments: {
        type: String,
        trim: true
    },
    creator: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    },
    contacts: [ContactSchema],
    address: String,
}, {timestamps: {createdAt: 'created', updatedAt: 'updated'}});
```

Alas, when I save the `Client` object, no _id is assigned to the saved `Contact`.

But when I use this schema:

client.js:

```
/**
 * Client Schema
 */
var ClientSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true
    },
    comments: {
        type: String,
        trim: true
    },
    creator: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    },
    contacts: [{
        name: String,
        role: String,
        phone: String,
        email: String,
        primary: Boolean
    }],
    address: String,
}, {timestamps: {createdAt: 'created', updatedAt: 'updated'}});
```

Contacts are saved with an auto-generated _id.

The way I save the clients is very straight forward:

```
var client = new Client(req.body);
client.creator = req.user;
client.save(function (err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return res.status(500).json({
            error: 'Cannot save the client'
        });
    }

    res.json(client);
});
```

And the contents of req.body is:

```
{ 
    name: 'A name for the client',
    contacts: [ { 
        name: 'A name for the contact',
        email: 'noy@test.com',
        role: 'UFO' 
    }] 
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you plz add how you generate and save an object i think the error is in there.

Comment: @Sprotte sure, I've edited the question. Thanks!

Comment: How do you create the `Client` model?

Comment: @kba nothing special: `mongoose.model('Client', ClientSchema);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I was completely off here. My problem was the way I was requiring the schema.
I was using:

```
var ContactSchema = require('./contact');
```

to get the schema, but I didn't add `module.exports = ContactSchema;` at the end of the contact.js file.

Thanks to this question: [MongoDB: How to use one schema as sub-document for different collections defined in different files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24126985/mongodb-how-to-use-one-schema-as-sub-document-for-different-collections-defined) 
I was able to solve mine (world's weirdest behavior though, since everything else was working).